# How to generate a sample time series data set containing multiple individuals of different length (rows)?

Tags: r, time-series

I want to simulate a time series data frame that contains observations of 5 variables that were taken on 10 individuals. I want the number of rows (observations) to be different between each individual. For instance, I could start with something like this:

```r
ID = rep(c("alp", "bet", "char", "delta", "echo"), times = c(1000,1200,1234,980,1300))
```

in which case `ID` represents each unique individual (I would later turn this into a factor), and the number of times each `ID` was repeated would represent the length of measurements for that factor. I would next need to create a column called `Time` with sequences from 1:1000, 1:1200, 1:1234, 1:980, and 1:1300 (to represent the length of measurements for each individual). Lastly I would need to generate 5 columns of random numbers for each of the 5 variables. 
There are tons of ways to go about generating this data set, but what would be the most practical way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
ID = c("alp", "bet", "char", "delta", "echo")
num = c(1000,1200,1234,980,1300)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(ID, num), num = sequence(num))
df[paste0('rand', seq_along(ID))] <- rnorm(length(ID) * sum(num))

head(df)
#   ID num      rand1       rand2       rand3      rand4       rand5
#1 alp   1  0.1340386  0.95900538  0.84573154  0.7151784 -0.07921171
#2 alp   2  0.2210195  1.67105483 -1.26068288  0.9171749 -0.09736927
#3 alp   3  1.6408462  0.05601673 -0.35454240 -2.6609228  0.21615254
#4 alp   4 -0.2190504 -0.05198191 -0.07355602  1.1102771  0.88246516
#5 alp   5  0.1680654 -1.75323736 -1.16865142 -0.4849876  0.20559750
#6 alp   6  1.1683839  0.09932759 -0.63474826  0.2306168 -0.61643584
```

I have used `rnorm` here, you can use any other distribution to generate random numbers.